# What is the correct way to create permission in Android(Python for Android)?

Tags: python, android, kivy, python-for-android, p4a

I want to turn off/on wifi in Kivy App. For this work, I used:

```
from wifidroid.wifi import WifiManager
wifi = WifiManager()
wifi.EnabledWifi(False) #True
```

I also added `permission` in Buildozer.spec:

> android.permissions = CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, INTERNET

This method works fine, But the problem is that I have to give "allow" every time for turn off wifi.

[image]

I researched this, came to the conclusion that I could create `permission` in the program as well. so I used the following code.

```
if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE])
```

After adding the above three lines, The app crashes during execution. In debug mode it gives this message.

```
08-31 01:48:47.898 32527 32549 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : /data/user/0/org.kivy.oscservice/files/app
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : calculated paths to be...
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : /data/user/0/org.kivy.oscservice/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.kivy.oscservice/files/app/_python_bundle/modules
08-31 01:48:47.899 32527 32549 I python  : set wchar paths...
08-31 01:48:48.020 32527 32549 I python  : Initialized python
08-31 01:48:48.020 32527 32549 I python  : AND: Init threads
08-31 01:48:48.024 32527 32549 I python  : AND: Ran string
08-31 01:48:48.024 32527 32549 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
08-31 01:48:49.050 32476 32506 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
08-31 01:48:49.050 32476 32506 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
08-31 01:48:49.054 32476 32506 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

How can I create a permission message that the user will allow forever?

Comment: perhaps you need to include the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your `request_permissions()`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I added this, But it was not resolved.